# No puedo mostrar los datos de post

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, formularios

tengo un archivo html, con un botón modal que cuando lo pulsas se abre un modal en el cual tiene un formulario, con un campo input y un botón buscar, cuando pulsas en el botón buscar te muestra en otra pagina los datos enviados por post, esa es mi idea.

El primer archivo contiene el botón modal que al pulsarlo va al segundo archivo que contiene el cuerpo del modal con el formulario de búsqueda, al insertar los datos y pulsar en el botón buscar mostraría los datos enviados por post, pero el problema es que en mi caso muestra:

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

```css
/* funcion que se encarga de cargar el contenido del modal desde un archivo externo */
function mostrarModal(id, ruta) {
    // se encarga de apuntar a la etiqueta el contenido que se va a cargar en ella
    $(id).load(ruta, function () {
        // se encarga de mostrar el contenido en el cuerpo del modal
        $(id).modal('show');
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- aqui va la imagen de pestaña  -->
    <link rel="icon" href='../php/funciones/assets/faviconArenas.png'>
    <!-- bootstrap importado css-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- aqui importamos la libreria de jquery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<!-- bootstrap importado js-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
    <div class='botones my-3 text-end'>
        <!-- Boton que al pulsarlo abre el modal para buscar a un jugador -->
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' data-bs-toggle='modal' onclick='mostrarModal("#btnBuscar","../buscar/buscar.php")'>
            Buscar por nombre jugador
        </button>
        <!-- cuerpo del modal de el boton buscar -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="btnBuscar" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        </div>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
        </div>
        <form role="form" action="procesoBuscar.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="input-group flex-nowrap">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                            <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z" />
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="txtNombreAbBuscar" placeholder="Introduce el nombre del jugador" aria-label="buscador" aria-describedby="addon-wrapping">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" name="submit" value='hello' class="btn btn-primary" id="busqueda">Buscar jugador</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```html
<?php

if (isset($_POST['txtNombreAbBuscar'])){
    print_r($_POST['txtNombreAbBuscar']);
}
?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué hay en `ruta` exactamente? Y, ¿por qué ese lío de ventanas que se abren por aquí y por allá? ¿No es mejor tener todo integrado en un solo contenedor? Los modales datan de los años 90, con el boom de Windows, pero hoy, un modal sólo tendría sentido como cuadro de diálogo obligatorio antes de pasar a una acción, no como contenedor o solicitador de datos. No entiendo ese empeño de seguir programando como en los 90. Los modales son una pésima experiencia de usuario hoy día.

Comment: la ruta del segundo archivo, como seria el planteamiento con el boom de windows, lo desconozco

Comment: ¿Y esa ruta funciona? Imprímela con `console.log(ruta);` revisa la consola, copia/pega para probar esa ruta en el navegador.

Comment: si se imprime la ruta

Comment: Dado que `ruta` no parece ser una ruta absoluta, conviene que nos digas cómo están organizados tus archivos, ¿el HTML en qué carpeta está? Según esto: `../buscar/buscar.php` en el directorio padre del HTML debe haber una carpeta `buscar` y allí un archivo llamado `buscar.php`. Muéstranos tu árbol de directorios y archivos.

Comment: lo acabo de subir

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo donde tienes el `form` (penúltimo bloque de código de tu pregunta)?

Comment: el archivo es buscar.php, que luego envia los datos a procesoBuscar.php

Comment: `procesoBuscar.php` y `buscar.php` están en la misma carpeta, entonces esto está mal: `"../buscar/buscar.php"` tienes que ponerlo así simplemente: **`"buscar.php"`**

Comment: A ver, el HTML está en `buscar.php` o en `procesoBuscar.php`. Si no explicas el contexto con claridad es difícil ayudar. Si tienes el HTML en `buscar.php` tienes que poner `procesoBuscar.php` en el `button`.

Comment: perdón me explique mal, el botón lo tengo en inde.php, que esta en la carpeta php, el cuerpo del modal donde esta el formulario, esta en la carpeta buscar, en el archivo buscar.php

Comment: Prueba a poner la ruta así en el botón: `"buscar/buscar.php"`

Comment: nada, solo si creo una carpeta procesos, meto hay dentro el archivo procesoBuscar.php, y en el action lo llamo  action="../procesos/procesoBuscar.php"  si me lo muestra, pero si los archivos son hermanos, no lo muestra

Comment: con el windows boom como seria?

Comment: No, nada de windows boom, precisamente ese lío de modales, propio del boom de Windows en los 90 es hoy un lastre que produce un código complicado, como en tu caso. Mi comentario iba en la línea de evitar programar así. Hoy día, con Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript tú puedes tener todo en un solo contenedor (una misma página) y desde ahí gestionar todo sin necesidad de modales, ni de recargar páginas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero que la petición la hagas por ajax, esto te permitirá enviar cualquier dato,
veo que desas usar el modal y consumir los datos con un load, no veo que sea necesario,
podrías utilizarlo cuando el usuario haga click en tu botón de buscar;
pero debes priorizar qque es lo que continua, en tu caso el proceso es que
cuando el usuario haga click en "buscar" hacer la petición vía ajax, consultar los datos,
incrustar los datos en el cuerpo del modal y hasta el último mostrar el modal,
te deje un ejemplo lo más sencillo posible, con la última versión de Jquery y Bootsrap (5.2) 
Espero te sirva mi respuesta.
index.php o index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
         <meta charset="UTF-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <title>Hagamos la web</title>
         <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
         </head>
      <body>

<div class="container mt-1">
    <input id="search" class="form-group" value="buscar texto"/>
    <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="abrirModal()">buscar</button>
</div>


<div id="nuevo-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Paises</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- incluyendo jquery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>  
<!-- incluyendo cdn bootstrap.js -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    function abrirModal(){
        //aqui si lanza el click del modal
        $.ajax({
            url: "datos.php?param="+ $("#search").val(),
            type: 'GET',
            datype: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //datos desde php
                var dataJson = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log(dataJson);  
                var body = ``;
                for(index in dataJson){
                    body += `${index}: ${dataJson[index].name} <br>`;
                }                
                //agrrego los datos al cuerpo del modal
                $('.modal-body').html(body);
                var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal('#nuevo-modal', {
                    keyboard: false //no cerrar el modal mediante la tecla ESC
                });
                myModal.show();
            },
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

datos.php

```
<?php

//usar el parametro del metodo GET 
// echo $_GET["param"];

//consulta BD 
$data = array(
    array('id'=>0,  'name'=>'México'),
    array('id'=>23, 'name'=>'EU'),
    array('id'=>23, 'name'=>'Inglaterra'),
);

echo json_encode ($data);
```

?>